# Nvidia driver 418 missing dependencies

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, nvidia

I was following this guide: https://github.com/lutris/lutris/wiki/Installing-drivers and 
when I tried to install the driver, it throwed this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-418 : Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-418 (= 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-418 (= 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried fixing it using multiple different ways:

- I tried to install it using -f, it throws same output regardless
- I updated and upgraded aptitude
- sudo apt-get clean, output is empty
- sudo dpkg --configure -a, output is empty
- sudo apt-get -f install, output is this:

  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
- sudo apt-get build-dep build-essential but that throws an error:

  E: Unable to find a source package for build-essential

What am I supposed to do? I am using Linux Mint 19.1 and I have GTX 1060 graphics card.

Comment: Crossoni, if you would like to post the instructions from that link into an Answer, ping me here and I will reopen the question. Posting "answers" in the "question' is not how the Stack Exchange format is supposed to work.  Thank you!

Comment: @JeffSchaller Sure, I can post the answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing my old nvidia driver with the command

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

before installing the new driver fixed the problem. I would have hoped that the Lutris guide would have said anything about removing old nvidia driver first, but I guess that it should be common sense.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The versions of the dependency packages ("418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu **18.04.1**") indicate you're trying to install a version intended for Ubuntu 18.04 rather than Ubuntu/Mint 19.1. Probably the `xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-418` and `libnvidia-cfg1-418` packages are available within the PPA repository, but they depend on 18.04-specific versions of other components, so the package manager is correct in refusing to install them.</strike>

Despite similar version numbers, Mint 19.1 is actually based on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS after all. So the above was false, and I don't know what is going on here.

Comment: I tried installing nvidia-driver-430 and it throws almost the same error: 
nvidia-driver-430 : Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430 (= 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     
Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-430 (= 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed

Comment: Your repository configuration must still be referring to 18.04 then. If you've recently upgraded from 18.04 to 19.10, you might try removing and reinstalling that PPA: `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`, then `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`.

Comment: I have not upgraded, this Linux Mint 19.1 is the first build I have ever had. I followed your instructions for removing and reinstalling the PPA, but it still throws the same error.

Comment: Strange. Perhaps the PPA has an error then, or perhaps you have something else installed that specifically depends on 18.04 version of the drivers.

Comment: When I use command cat /etc/upstream-release/lsb-release it shows that my DISTRIB_RELEASE is 18.04. It also says that DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION is "Ubuntu 18.04 LTS". Is there something wrong with my build?

Comment: Ah, it looks like Mint 19.1 is based on Ubuntu 18.04 after all. My mistake...

Answer (score -1):

Run this first,

```
Solution  root@vdesk:~# for FILE in $(dpkg-divert --list | grep nvidia-340 | awk '{print $3}'); do dpkg-divert --remove $FILE; done
```

Then install it from ppa,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-390
```